# Editable input text with blur() jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with jquery blur() function
This is the code:

```
<a class="quick_edit_title" s="1" u="/administrator/user-group/index/edit/1">Admin</a>
<a class="quick_edit_title" s="1" u="/administrator/user-group/index/edit/2">User</a>
<a class="quick_edit_title" s="1" u="/administrator/user-group/index/edit/3">Mod</a>
```

I'm using Jquery Ajax with Editable element when using click

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.quick_edit_title').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            var url = $(this).attr('u');
            var status = $(this).attr('s');
            var title = $(this).html();
            var old_element = this;
            var input = $("<input type='text' size='45' value='" + title.replace(/'/gi, "\\'") + "' class='input_quick_edit'/>");

            //$(this).replaceWith(input).blur(function() {
            //alert(this.value);
            //});  

        });
    });
});
```

When i click editable `<a>`. Element `<input/>` is added but when I'm using jquery's `blur()` function, I can't get the `value` of `<input/>` element and come back element `<a>` when blur.

Comment: I think you need to switch your blur statement around (in your comments)  You need to do something like `$(this).blur(function(){$(this).html(input);)}`

Comment: (not an answer) Using custom attributes except for data-* is invalid in HTML5. You should use `data-status` instead of `s` as attribute name. Same for `u` -> `data-url`. Then they can also be retrieved using `var url = $(this).data('status');`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.quick_edit_title', function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('u');
    var status = $(this).attr('s');
    var title = $(this).html();
    var input = $("<input type='text' size='45' value='" + title.replace(/'/gi,"\\'") + "' class='input_quick_edit'/>");

    $(this).replaceWith(input); 
}).on('blur', '.input_quick_edit', function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

No need to iterate through with `.each()` and assign click handlers for the class, you can just make the class click handler, replace the content, and chain a `blur` function.